# How to find and replace string with another string from input in C++?

Tags: c++, str-replace

So I want to find a word "ha" from my string(str) and replace it with "wk" from another string(str2) like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    string str2("ha");
    while (str.find(str2) != std::string::npos) {
    str.replace(str.find(str2),str2.length(),"wk");
    cout << str << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that i can't make it work when i start the var1 with another word like "lol haha".
[not working when not haha at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybSJk.jpg)[1]

Thank You :)

Comment: Beware `using namespace std;`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721

Comment: your problem is with your input, get it with std::getline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for `std::string` only reads until it finds a whitespace character.  You probably want [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
getline( std::cin, str );
```

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, i know this is stupid. But idk how to do that, could you help me again ? Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry didnt know you can click on it, my bad. i thought it was blue cause it was code XD. Thank you

Comment: Thank you it works as i expected now. Thank you very much :)